# Using column label as formatting condition in excel pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

I have pivot table in excel with sample  data as attached. I now want to apply conditional formatting as red background  where 
 - data is between 10 to 25 AND
 - year is 2011 and 2012.

=AND(C1="2011",OR(C2>10,C2<25))

how do i make cells example c2,c3,d2 red based on condition of year. Without Year condition it is working fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on:

> data is between 10 to 25

and

> year is 2011 and 2012

- New conditional formatting rule > Formula:

  ```
  =AND(C2>10,C2<25,OR(C$1=2011,C$1=2012))
  ```
- Apply to your range `C2:F7`

Result:

[image]

But offcourse, if you only interested in 2011 and 2012, you can also just apply `=AND(C2>10,C2<25)` to those two columns only....

Comment: thanks! just curious to know. what is 011,012 in OR Condition?

Comment: @user2490024, it's a mishap from my side, not sure how those commas ended up there :). Changed now.

Comment: its not working. Its working in normal table but not pivot. Can I refer columns in conditional formatting column? If I write =C2>10 it works fine. If I write AND(c1="2011",c2>10) , it breaks.